# Jacoco gradle multi module

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, jacoco

We have a gradle project with mutliple modules - so each module - eg admin, ends up having something like this:

```
task admintest(type: Test) {
    description = "Tests of admin"
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.admintest.output.classesDir
    classpath += sourceSets.admintest.runtimeClasspath
}
check.dependsOn admintest
```

now - we are generating a jacoco report - the report actually includes all the classes from all the different modules, but only has *coverage* from the tests that ran as part of the main module, ie the "test" task - while the admintests and others run, the coverage is always zero.   How do I get jacoco to also pick up the coverage from the admintests, and other module tests?

Answer (score 1):

Found it - for those who are trying to do this - the secret sauce is to specify the other modules test tasks in the executionData

eg:

```
jacocoTestReport {
    executionData test, admintest, commontest
}
```

Comment: This question and this answer are a tiny bit misleading, Your project setup is a single project, with multiple sourceSets, each having a dedicated 'test' task (that will activate the jacoco code coverage and produce execution data), but the jacoco report is a single task that necessarily need to aggregate. Your answer shows that you simply need to reference the test tasks or sourcesets.

Comment: Another common setup is to have multiple sub-projects instead of separate sourcesets. In this case, you can still produce an aggregate code coverage report with a single task in the root project, which you can accomplish similarly with proper referencing of the sub-project, OR you have the option of using the JacocoMerge task to explicitly aggregate the executiondata files produced for each sub project, before creating the report from that aggregate execution data file.

Answer (score 0):

This is old thread , but this might help someone :

We only need this in build.gradle of root project.

1. Define a common location
2. Provide same to sonarqube as well.

   ```
    plugins {
        ..
        id "org.sonarqube"
    }
    apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'

    allprojects {
        apply plugin: 'jacoco'
    }

    task jacocoRootReport(type: JacocoReport) {
        dependsOn = subprojects.test
        description = 'Generates aggregate report from all subprojects.'
        .....
        reports {
            xml.enabled true
            xml.destination(file("${jacoco.reportsDir}/all-tests/jacocoRootReport.xml"))
            csv.enabled false
        }  
    }

    sonarqube {
        properties {
           property "sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", jacocoRootReport.reports.xml.destination
        }
    }
   ```